# Android: Reading External Storage in Native Code

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-external-storage

I've been trying to copy some `assets` to `external storage` in my Java code, and pass the directory to my native `C/C++` code to read from. However, the problem is, if there is `no SD card` on the device the `getExternalFilesDir()` returns something like **"storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/files"**, which when I pass to the `native code` to fopen and fread, causes the app to crash. I believe the reason is because the directory is artificial or a symbolic link or something of the sort. However, even if I use the `stdlib.h function realpath()` on the path passed down to the native code, it still crashes. If however, I manually replace `emulated/0/` with `emulated/legacy/` in the path, `realpath()` suddenly works and converts it to the actual location the files are stored, and the `fread()` works fine with no crashes. Somehow `emulated/legacy/` is the actual symbolic link and `emulated/0/` is something else?

The problem is I want to write code that is reliable in the long run, regardless of changes to the way Android organizes external storage and these symbolic links/virtual filesystems. I also want the code to work regardless of which device it is run on (I believe these emulated directories are different depending on the device).

Is there some way to get an `external storage directory` in Java that can be written to and reliably read from in native code as well, without doing this ***replace-with-legacy*** hack?

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Edit : Calling `getPath()`, `getCanonicalPath()` and `getAbsolutePath()` on the `File` returned by `getExternalFilesDir()` all return the same path.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark.  What happens if you pass getExternalFilesDir().getCanonicalPath() to your native code?

Comment: Also, run the command `adb shell` to get a shell into your Android device and explore the filesystem.

Comment: getPath(), getAbsolutePath(), getCanonicalPath() all return the same emulated/0/ path... I have been using adb shell that's how I found the legacy path to replace the one that is returned.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() instead of getExternalFilesDir()?

Comment: Anyway, I use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() in java and pass that path to native code and it works just fine...

Comment: That does help actually. The problem with using that directory for app-specific files though, is that if your app gets uninstalled, all those files will persist and take up space for no reason.

The directory returned by getExternalFilesDir() is app-specific and so is removed when the application is uninstalled.